# Error reading MIME multipart body part. Client Disconnected

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, system.io.file

So I am running into this error with ng-file-upload in c# from https://github.com/stewartm83/angular-fileupload-sample. If I run his live Demo I can see the same issue in which larger images do not upload.

```
 System.IO.IOException: Error reading MIME multipart body part. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The client disconnected.
```

I believe this is due to the sizing of your images that you are uploading. When I upload a larger image in the Demo, it seems to only have uploaded 1/8 of the image. I tried incorporating the

`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="30000000"> and 
     <security>
     <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000">
     </requestFiltering>
</security>`

into your WebConfig file but had no luck with many other solutions. The interesting thing is that you are getting a client disconnected, which is something that I wouldn't have expected. I still haven't figured out a solution for this, so if anyone has a clue that would be great.

Comment: Hey mate, also try the executionTimeout like <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="214748364" executionTimeout="3600"/> with debug set to false. Let me know if it changes anything.

Comment: Hi man, have you found a way to solve this issue?

Thanks, Kenny.